# importing animations in Blender, weird rotations/locations

Tags: matrix, blender, skeletal-animation, transformation

This is for the Blender 2.6 API.

There are two problems:

**1.** When I import a single animation frame from my animation file to Blender, all bones look fine.
But when I import multiple (all of the frames), just the first one looks right, seems like newer frames are affected by older ones, so you get slightly off positions/rotations.

This is true when both assigning `PoseBone.matrix` and `PoseBone.matrix_basis`.

```
bone_index = 0

# for each frame:
for frame_index in range(frame_count):
    # for each pose bone: add a key
    for bone_name in bone_names: # "bone_names" - a list of bone names I got earlier
        pose.bones[bone_name].matrix = animation_matrices[frame_index][bone_index] # "animation_matrices" - a nested list of matrices generated from reading a file

        # create the 'keys' for the Action from the poses
        pose.bones[bone_name].keyframe_insert('location', frame = frame_index+1)
        pose.bones[bone_name].keyframe_insert('rotation_euler', frame = frame_index+1)
        pose.bones[bone_name].keyframe_insert('scale', frame = frame_index+1)

        bone_index += 1

    bone_index = 0
```

Again, it seems like previous frames are affecting latter ones, because if I import a single frame from the middle of the animation, it looks fine.

**2.** I can't assign armature-space animation matrices read from a file to a skeleton with hierarchy (parenting).

In Blender 2.4 you could just assign them to `PoseBone.poseMatrix` and bones would deform perfectly whether the bones had a hierarchy or none at all.

In Blender 2.6, there's `PoseBone.matrix_basis` and `PoseBone.matrix`. While `matrix_basis` is relative to parent bone, `matrix` isn't, the API says it's in object space. So it should have worked, but doesn't. So I guess we need to calculate a local space matrix from our armature-space animation matrices from the files.
So I tried multiplying it ( `PoseBone.matrix` ) with `PoseBone.parent.matrix.inverted()` in both possible orders with no luck, still weird deformations.

Comment: I would flag this for migration to blender.stackexchange.com, but it's too old

Comment: There is a dedicated community only for Blender.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix_basis of a pose bone is the transform required to go from the bind pose to the current pose, in parent relative space. It's NOT the final matrix that you want.

`pose_bone.matrix_basis = bind_matrix.inverted() * animation_matrix`

Both bind_matrix and animation_matrix in the above example are in parent relative space.

Comment: My animation_matrix (the one from the file) is in armature space, so the above code gives  wrong results... When there is no parent relation, it looks fine, except still has the problem #1.

Comment: I can post a video example of the problem (wrong on in Blender and correct one in game engine)

Comment: Solution for problem #1 seems to be using `keyframe_insert('rotation_quaternion')` instead. Still can't fix problem # 2.